# Get value of option of the dropdown menu and filter table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to click in the dropdown menu and I get the value of the selected option. After that I would like to filter a field of the bootstrap-table and it show only the records with this field.

[image]

At moment my code of the jquery is this:

```
$('#edicion').click(function(v){
                console.log(v.target.value);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left  btn-group" style="padding-right: 10px;">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">EDICIÓ<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" id="edicion">
        <?php 
            $result = dbQuery($conn, "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_edicion");
                while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
                    <li><a href=#><?php echo $row[1] .' '. $row[2]; ?></a></li>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
      </ul>
</div>
```

`#edicion` is the id of the Dropdown Menu and at moment only it shows in the console the message 'undefined'.

[image]

I do not know how to get the value of the option nor how to filter the table applying this value at field.

To filtering:

[image]

After choose option:

[image]

The head of the table disappear :(

Comment: i made change in my answer , please check for solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the change event to get selected dropdown value

```
$('#edicion').change(function(){
 console.log($(this).val());
});
```

For filtering the tables you can use html5's data attributes.
Add

```
<tr data-ediction='edion-12'></tr>
```

On dropdown change hide all rows that's don't contain that value:-

```
  $("tr[data-ediction!='eion-12']").hide();
  $("tr[data-ediction='eion-12']").show();
```

Check out here https://jsfiddle.net/nar2bnx1/

Updated with header always available:-
https://jsfiddle.net/nar2bnx1/1/

Updated with multiple filters:-
https://jsfiddle.net/nar2bnx1/2/

Comment: It's perfect! Thanks!!

Comment: It's works but when I select the edition it show/hide the head of the table too. I would be better does not hide/show the head of the table.

Comment: it should not, it should just hide the tr, share what you did

Comment: I have updated the question and I put two screenshots, the first without the option selection of the dropdown menu and the second after that.

Comment: Thanks @ALOK! How do it do to filter the all fields of the table not only for each pagination? Your code affect only to records showed in page 1 of the table the other pages does not filtering :(

Comment: how did you add a pagination? is it from serverside or clientside?

Comment: It's from clientside

Comment: can you share the code? you should call the function i created after pagination data is loaded

Comment: Yes I can. https://jsfiddle.net/ruzD/oj5khemq/ I use a query and php and create the table.

Comment: i can't see pagination, are you using datatables?

Comment: Yes I use a database. It doesn't in the cloud

Comment: i meant datatables, ok i guess you didn't. You should call the function on pagination click, that should do.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code

```
<select id="edicion">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

$(document).on("change", '#edicion', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/2fkb95ur/1/

```
$('#edicion li').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/2fkb95ur/2/

Comment: I have updated my code with the HTML code to make dropdown.

Comment: Did you got solution for your problem?

Comment: I don't use the tags select and option to make a dropdown menu.

Comment: Then how do you create that select field

Comment: I have put the code in the question. With li tags and ul

Comment: For dynamic content you need to use on function. Please look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For single select elements, to get the selected value:

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

To get the selected text:

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the click event of the li and as per the HTML content is bind into the `a` anchor tag , so on click of the li tag find the `a` anchor tag and find the content inside the tag. Below code is help to find the content.

HERE is the html code for better solution:

```
<div class="dropdown pull-left  btn-group" style="padding-right: 10px;">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">EDICIÓ<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" id="edicion">
        <?php 
            $result = dbQuery($conn, "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_edicion");
                while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
                    <li><a href='#' data-value="<?php echo $row[2] ?>"><?php echo $row[1] .' '. $row[2]; ?></a></li>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the click event of the `li` tag

```
   $('#edicion li').click(function(v){
                    console.log($(this).find('a').data('value'));
    });
```

Comment: it show this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined

Comment: @ruzD , now check and one more thing $row[2] is your value?

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.